# Live chart in Shiny with R language

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to draw active (Live Continues) graph dynamically when i browse the CSV file. And from that user will select the two values (X and Y) from the selectInput. According to the choice of the user's the active graph should be generated dynamically.

I'm trying since early morning. If i put the plot in infinite while loop then it does not display.  But i don't understand what to do. If anybody can help me then it would be very beneficial for me. Here I'm attaching my two files i.e UI.R and SERVER.R

```
ui.r

library(shiny)


shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),


  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('datafile', 'Choose CSV file',accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma- 
                                                       separated-values,text/plain')),
      numericInput("obs", "Enter the number of rows to display:", 5),
      selectInput("sep", "Seperator", choices = c(Comma = ',', semicolon = ';', 
                                                  tab = "\t", space = " " ))

    ),


    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel( id = "tabs",

                   tabPanel("Display File", tableOutput("input_file")),
                   tabPanel("Generate Plot",dashboardSidebar(h4("Select columns from CSV to plot"),
                                                             uiOutput("selectX"),uiOutput("selectY"), 
                                                             radioButtons("type","Select File Type:", choices = list("png","pdf")),
                                                             selectInput(inputId = "plot",
                                                                         label = "Select Plot:",
                                                                         choices = c("BoxPlot","BarPlot","Simple Plot","Plot with Density"),
                                                                         selected = "BoxPlot"),


                                                             colourInput("color", "Select colour", value = "blue")),
                            plotOutput("plot")))


    )
  )
)
    )



server.r



library(shiny)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  #This function is repsonsible for reading a csv file
  file <- reactive({
    req(input$datafile)
    infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    read.csv(infile$datapath,nrows = input$obs, sep = input$sep)

  })

  #This function is repsonsible for reading numeric fields from csv file
  filedata <- reactive({
    req(input$datafile)
    infile <- input$datafile
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    file<-read.csv(infile$datapath,nrows = input$obs, sep = input$sep)
    nums <- unlist(lapply(file, is.numeric))
    file[,nums]
  })

  output$input_file <- renderTable({

    file()
  })



  #This function responsible to Select the X value while drawing the plot.
  output$selectX <- renderUI({
    df <- filedata()
    if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)
    items=names(df)
    names(items)=items
    selectInput("x", "Select X-axis:",items)
  })

  #This function responsible to Select the Y value while drawing the plot.
  output$selectY <- renderUI({
    df <- filedata()
    if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)
    items=names(df)
    names(items)=items
    selectInput("y", "Select Y-axis:",items)
  })

  #This function is responsible for drawing the plots
  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    cont <- TRUE

    req(input$x)
    req(input$y)
    df <- filedata()


    while(cont == TRUE){
    if(input$plot == "BoxPlot"){

      boxplot(df[,input$x],df[,input$y],col = input$color,xlab = input$x, ylab = input$y, main = "Complete Blood Count Data" )

    }
    else if(input$plot == "BarPlot")
    {
      barplot(df[,input$x],df[,input$y],col = input$color,xlab = input$x, ylab = input$y, main = "Complete Blood Count Data")
    }  

    else if(input$plot == "Simple Plot"){
      plot(df[,input$x],df[,input$y],col = input$color,xlab = input$x, ylab = input$y, main = "Complete Blood Count Data")
    }
    else if(input$plot == "Plot with Density"){
      plot(density(df[,input$x],df[,input$y]),col = input$color,xlab = input$x, ylab = input$y, main = "Complete Blood Count Data")
    }

    }
  })


})
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you definitely shouldn't use the expression

```
while(cont == TRUE){
...
}
```

For a continuous update already responding reactivity.

Secondly, your plot is not displayed because you use the same id for

```
selectInput(inputId = "plot", ....)
```

and

```
 plotOutput("plot")
```

but they must be unique. If you replace it like this

```
  selectInput(inputId = "plotType",
   label = "Select Plot:",
   choices = c("BoxPlot","BarPlot","Simple Plot","Plot with Density"),
   selected = "BoxPlot")
```

and

```
if(input$plotType == "BoxPlot"){

      boxplot(df[,input$x],df[,input$y],col = input$color,xlab = input$x, ylab = input$y, main = "Complete Blood Count Data" )

    }
    else if(input$plotType == "BarPlot")
    {
      barplot(df[,input$x],df[,input$y],col = input$color,xlab = input$x, ylab = input$y, main = "Complete Blood Count Data")
    }  

    else if(input$plotType == "Simple Plot"){
      plot(df[,input$x],df[,input$y],col = input$color,xlab = input$x, ylab = input$y, main = "Complete Blood Count Data")
    }
    else if(input$plotType == "Plot with Density"){
      plot(density(df[,input$x],df[,input$y]),col = input$color,xlab = input$x, ylab = input$y, main = "Complete Blood Count Data")
    }
```

it would be works right.

Comment: Actually, when i remove the while loop that time it works fine. But i want to make it live graph which rotates continuesly that's why i put it in while loop. I want to rotate it continuesly. I want to be very clear with you about LIVE CHART. When the new data entered that time this effect should be affected on the graph. Now can you suggest me,  Instead of while loop, what can i use for making it live chart?

Comment: @Heena, if you mean that you need reactive plots update when .csv file was changed, you should consider function reactiveFileReader. Any other reactivity that depends on dashboard objects like selectInput, numericInput and so on is already exist by using renderPlot and reactive inputs.